# SQL Count on items from same column

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following records:

```html
BookingTimeStamp    BookingReloc    AEType
2016-01-14 23:19:24.773 LVWCQL  Seat
2016-01-14 23:19:24.773 LVWCQL  Seat
2016-01-14 23:19:24.773 LVWCQL  Seat
2016-01-14 16:45:29.450 KCCEMG  Baggage
2016-01-14 16:34:07.117 MEZYPN  Insurance
2016-01-14 16:08:40.617 CJXDFK  Insurance
2016-01-14 16:08:40.617 CJXDFK  Insurance
2016-01-14 16:08:40.617 CJXDFK  Insurance
2016-01-14 16:08:40.617 CJXDFK  Insurance
2016-01-14 15:14:51.633 JMILRY  Seat
```

I  want to count the repetitions of values in the column AEType.

Desired output:

```
Seat = 4 

Baggaage = 1

Insurance =5
```

Is it possible to get it in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'group by' it groups sql entries by the distinct parameters and 'count(*)' can be used to count number of sql entries for each distinct AEType.

```
select AEType,count(*) from Table_Name group by AEType;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select AEType,count(*) from table_name
group by AEType;
```